# Time of day display

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to get a time of day script I had from a long time ago working again, but I also want to add some ajax scripting to it as well. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious or not completing it fully. I think I am missing more of the code but not sure were.
Here is what I have:

**date.js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
      var now = new Date();
      var hours = now.getHours();
      var msg;
      if (hours < 07) msg = "Good Morning";
      else if (hours < 12) msg = "Good Afternoon";
      else if (hours < 18) msg = "Good Evening";
      $('#time p').text(msg);
    });
});
</script>
```

Could I add

```
 <?php the_date(); echo "<br />"; ?>
```

in the location I want to display the text and getting it working again.
 If not Were and what would I add the output for it to display the text at those times? Like I said I'm sure it something simple.

Comment: You can put the output of PHP inside the `$('#time p').text("<?php echo 'right here'; ?>");` and let Javascript put it in the `#time p` element.

Comment: However, that means you have to embed the java script code into the main page..

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Here is what i have done and for some reason it still isnt working. i moved the java to the index.php file as suggested.  and made some minor adjustments. i went to put the output by adding ("<?php echo '$('time').text'; ?>") it still showing a blank area were it should be the time.Thanks Rob

Comment: Really, what are you trying to do? You want to "add" some ajax, I dont see and noor have you given a reason why ajax is needed. What does `the_date()` do and printing out Javascript with PHP without using variables makes little to no sense.

Comment: Sorry let me back up. someone i know is running a radio type site but everything is automated that hourly it changes playlist... he came to me because scast v2 is giving him issues for stats update using ajax . I personally haven't worked with scast scripting in ages and didn't want to spend alot of time looking over the updated scripts with scast v2. i remembered back in the day i used a script that the texts changes at that time. he however wants it to be like an hourly thing (text change once an hour) but wants some ajax so it will change so noone will have to refresh hope it helps